# Swift class/struct implicitly conforms to NSObjectProtocol?

Tags: ios, swift, casting, nsobjectprotocol

A while ago I faced strange Swift issue. When I try to cast Swift object to NSObjectProtocol in debug - it executes successfully. But when this code executes in AppStore build, it casts to nil.

```
import Foundation

final class MyClass {
    let testP: String = "123"
}

struct MyStruct {
    let testP: String = "123"
}

let myClass = MyClass()
let myStruct = MyStruct()

print(myClass) // >> __lldb_expr_1.MyClass
print(myClass as! NSObjectProtocol) // >> __lldb_expr_1.MyClass
print(myStruct as! NSObjectProtocol) // >> __lldb_expr_3.MyStruct(testP: "123")
```

When I cast struct to NSObjectProtocol I get such warning:

```
Cast from 'MyStruct' to unrelated type 'NSObjectProtocol' always fails
```

However, how you can see it successfully prints my struct.

So, the question is: is it bug or feature of Swift?)

PS: Pardon my French

Comment: https://forums.swift.org  https://bugs.swift.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa there is some unresolved issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it’s both bug and feature. https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-10495

Answer (score 0):

`NSObjectProtocol` has some methods for `AnyClass` and you need to conform with protocol's methods.

What you can read in offical Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobjectprotocol#declarations)

> An object that conforms to this protocol can be considered a
>   first-class object. Such an object can be asked about its:
>
> Class, and the place of its class in the inheritance hierarchy.
>
> Conformance to protocols.
>
> Ability to respond to a particular message.

See in an image a methods to conform any object with `NSObjectProtocol`.
[image]

Some other helpful information for you here: https://medium.com/a-swift-misadventure/why-swift-protocol-conforming-values-are-treated-as-value-types-by-default-9482c6809583

Comment: I understand why I've got warning, the question is: why is this struct successfully casts? despite warning...

Comment: By the way, NSObjectProtocol is not marked as class or AnyObject, so any struct may conform it.

Comment: Ok, it's just contract, so I can create struct, which will conform this protocol and handle these properties and methods as I wish

Comment: Show me you code with struct that conforms to that protocol

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an answer for my question)

Comment: Oh, my bad, but it strange, because in documentation NSObjectProtocol is not marked as class or AnyObject

Comment: For both struct and class i catch an error like this: `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x102caeb90)`.

Comment: To call `print(myClass as! NSObjectProtocol)` without errors you have to set         `final class MyClass : NSObject {let testP: String = "123"}`

Comment: I know how it should be, but I have no error with this code
Swift 5.0
XCode 10.2

Comment: My Xcode – Version 10.2 (10E125). And runtime crashes with your code

Comment: Maybe you have earlier version of Swift? I run playground and separate iOS project with Swift 5 and execute this code with only one warning and without runtime crashes